# Only one node in Cassandra AMI cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

When I start Cassandra AMI cluster with 4 nodes on AWS and open the OpsCenter there is only one node shown. I followed the fine [manual](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html)

I choose

```
Region      AMI
us-east-1   ami-ada2b6c4
```

I set the number of Ec2 instances to 4 and 
advanced details to "--clustername myDSCcluster --totalnodes 4 --version community"

[image]

Then after launching and waiting a bit I can only see one node in the cluster

```
ubuntu@ip-XXXX:~$ nodetool status
Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
Datacenter: us-east
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  XXX  59.24 KB   256     100.0%  XXXX  1c
```

Comment: I solved the problem my setting the security group to allow all traffic from anywhere.
But should really be like this: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html

Comment: since you've solved the issue, you might want to drop your solution into an answer and accept it.